# What `...` Do In An PHP Object Instantiation

Tags: php, magento2, objectinstantiation

Below is a function which we can find in core Magento 2 code.

```
protected function createObject($type, $args)
{
    return new $type(...array_values($args));
}
```

This function is instantiating `$type` (which is a string parameter) with the arguments `$args` (which is an array parameter).

What I am not getting is those 3 dots (`...`). Is this a valid syntax at all ? I never found such an object instantiation before !!

I tried to remove those dots and try to load a page. It gives fatal errors. So it seems that, those three dots are not accidentally come over there.

It seems like that code won't work for php-5.3 or lower versions. So it is something new which I couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: You can use google with a query `php three dots` You'll be surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list). They are new to PHP 5.6.x. This example is from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a great way to use array as function parameter or argument list.
Actually, It's replacement for the `func_get_args()` function.
[Variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)